# Replace animation width with custom div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

I made a simple, onlick animated input. Also i made some basic style, but i don't know how to replace `{width:'500px'}` width custom div. In this case: `.customwidth`.

Here is my full code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fast search" />
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.search { float:left; margin:10px 0px 0 10px;  height:31px; border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10); border-radius:15px;  }
.search i { float:right; margin:6px 10px; }
.search input { float:left; margin:2px 0px 0 10px; width:70px; height:25px; border:none; outline:none; }

.customwidth { width:500px; }
```

**JS**

```
$(".search").click(function () {
  $('.search input').animate({ width:'500px'}, { duration:200, specialEasing: { width: 'linear' } });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nvg9c9f6/2/)

I want to  change animation width from css file, so for that reason, i need to replace `width:'500px'` width `.customwidth` class.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `.addCLass('customwidth')`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nvg9c9f6/21/)**

```
$(".search").click(function () {
    $('.search input').addClass('customwidth');
});
```

Then in CSS use transition. I change the specificity of your `customwidth` selector for you wouldn't have to use !important. Might mess you up in the long run.

```
.search .customwidth {
    width:500px;
    transition: width .2s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was simple :)

Answer (score 1):

***JS & CSS & HTML***

```js
$(".search").click(function () {

    $('.search input').addClass('customwidth');
    
    
});
```

```css
.search { float:left; margin:10px 0px 0 10px;  height:31px; border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10); border-radius:15px;  }
.search i { float:right; margin:6px 10px; }
.search input { float:left; margin:2px 0px 0 10px; width:70px; height:25px; border:none; outline:none; }

.customwidth { width:500px !important; }
#test{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
        <input id="test" type="text" placeholder="Fast search" />
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

[DEMO-JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvg9c9f6/18/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a div with `customwidth` class and read its width to use it inside animation.

```
$(function(){
$(".search").click(function () {
     var $inspector = $("<div>").css('display', 'none').addClass('customwidth');
    $("body").append($inspector);

    var width = $inspector.css('width');
    $('.search input').animate({width:width},{ duration:200, specialEasing: { width: 'linear' } });
});
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nvg9c9f6/25/)**